# FormView Get Primary Key from Insert

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a Web Form application using VS2013 and Entity Framework 6.  Just upgraded from VS2012 and EF5 with no changes required.

There is an article editor form that once an item is inserted, will redirect the user to another form by Id. (Like a wizard)

Inserting records works without issue.  The problem is capturing the new record Id. InsertItem does return the new Id from the DB.

I have tried creating an event handler which does not seem to have the value.

Any idea how to capture the returned Id? Alternatives will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
// Web Form ArticleEditor code behind

public partial class ArticleEditor : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // page level variables
    private readonly IArticleRepository _repository = new ArticleRepository();

// more stuff here


 frmArticle_OnItemInserted(object sender, formViewInsertedEventArgs e)
 {
  // I assume the value can be captured here???
 }



// FormView
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="frmArticle" RenderOuterTable="True" 
    ItemType="WebApplication.BLL.Model.Article" DataKeyNames="ArticleId" 
    DefaultMode="ReadOnly" 
    SelectMethod="GetItem"
    InsertMethod="InsertItem"
    UpdateMethod="UpdateItem"
    DeleteMethod="DeleteItem" 
    OnItemInserted="frmArticle_OnItemInserted"  
    CssClass="FormView">

        <InsertItemTemplate>
    // controls here
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</FormView>

// repository ArticleRepository
    private readonly AppDbContext _db = new AppDbContext();

    public int InsertItem(ModelMethodContext modelMethodContext)
    {
        // create new model object
        var obj = new Article();

        // attempt to save model
        modelMethodContext.TryUpdateModel(obj);
        if (!modelMethodContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // model is in an invalid state
            return 0;
        }
        _db.Articles.Add(obj);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        return obj.ArticleId;
    }
```

Comment: After saving changes, the id field should have the value.

Comment: Emre, how do you access the id field?

Comment: I got this to work with a hack.  Since the repository was returning the id as the AffectedRows value, I used that value to redirect to the next page.                   Response.Redirect("~/path/ArticleEditor/" + e.AffectedRows + "/edit", true);